# webview links opens into a default browser

Tags: android

i'm new to android programing.my problem is that in my webview when i click on any link its opening to a new web browser i dont need this i want it to be opened in my app itself.can someone help me??

this is my code

```
title = extras.getString("title");
    url = extras.getString("url");
    TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(title);
    WebView myWebView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
    }
```

i tried this but my webview is not loading its showing a blank screen

Comment: Check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Comment: check this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-webviewclient-example/

Comment: thanku u for ur reply..its working perfectly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

  public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
  {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some info what you done in your code.

Comment: thanku...i missed to add  myWebView.loadUrl(url); this line above the method.